Error: Gradle Build Failure with Expo Modules
I'm using EAS to build app directly so I didn't needed to compile prebuild i.e (.android) file
Error: Gradle Build Failure with Expo Modules
I am encountering the following errors when building my project using Expo:

Task failed with an exception:

* Where:
Script '/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-modules-autolinking/scripts/android/autolinking_implementation.gradle' line: 408
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':expo'.
> A problem occurred configuring project ':expo-crypto'.
   > Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
      > compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle
      > Could not get unknown property 'release' for SoftwareComponent container of type org.gradle.api.internal.component.DefaultSoftwareComponentContainer.


Task failed with an exception:

* Where:
Script '/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/ExpoModulesCorePlugin.gradle' line: 85
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':expo'.
> Could not get unknown property 'release' for SoftwareComponent container of type org.gradle.api.internal.component.DefaultSoftwareComponentContainer.

Build Status: BUILD FAILED in 1m 37s
Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information.
I was building React Native App build on Expo using EAS directly. I tried to use EXPO DOCTOR to debug and fixed multiple potential issue still I'm having the same error.
